# Unable to render a table based on textinput in shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

Hello I am trying to control the input in my server function by an action button in my ui, however I have just not been able to do it. The input is submitted to a textinput which is observed in the serer function and then it reads a csv file. The csv file should then be rendered as a table post some manipulations. The observe event is working as expected, however it does not renders the table.

Below is the r code

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(bigrquery)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(reticulate)
library(tidyverse)
library(memisc) 

if (interactive()) {
  ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody())
  server <- function(input, output) {}


#Dashboard header carrying the title of the dashboard
header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Video Analyser", titleWidth = 250)  
#Sidebar content of the dashboard
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(disable = FALSE, 
                            sidebarMenu(
                              textInput('link', label = "Enter Valid Youtube URL"),
                              actionButton("update" ,"Run Analysis", icon("analysis"),
                                           class = "btn btn-primary")
                              )
                            )

frow1 <- fluidRow( 

  box(
    title = "Retention Labels"
    ,status = "primary"
    ,solidHeader = TRUE 
    ,collapsible = FALSE
    ,width = 4
    ,height = 400
    ,tableOutput('label')
    ,collapsed = FALSE
    ,br()

  ))
)

# combine the two fluid rows to make the body
body <- dashboardBody(frow1, frow2)

ui <- dashboardPage(title = 'Serato Audience Builder', header, sidebar, body, skin='blue')

server <- function(input, output) {
  source_python("pytho_for_r.py")
  observe({
    input$update
    x <- isolate(input$link)
    if(x == ""){
      print(x)}
    else{
      label_retention <- read.csv("label_retention.csv", header = TRUE)
      print(label_retention)

    }
  })

  output$label <- renderTable({
    if(!is.null(label_retention)){
      datatable(label_retention %>%
                  dplyr::select(Description, sum) %>%
                  mutate_if(is.character, str_to_upper) %>%
                  dplyr::mutate(sum = round(sum, 8)) %>%
                  dplyr::rename_at(1, ~ "Labels") %>%
                  dplyr::rename_at(2, ~ "Relative Audience Retention") %>%
                  dplyr::arrange_at("Relative Audience Retention", desc),
                  spacing = c("s"), striped = TRUE, bordered = TRUE, colnames = TRUE,
                  hover = TRUE)}
    else{print("No Video Available")}
  })
  # 
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
}
```

I was hoping if someone help me understand what am I missing here and help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks a lot in advance !!

Output of dput -

```
structure(list(Start = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), End = c(2.333333, 
2.333333, 2.333333, 2.333333, 2.333333, 2.333333), Description..Con = structure(c(25L, 
10L, 13L, 15L, 12L, 4L), .Label = c("3d modeling", "black", "black and white", 
"brand", "computer program", "computer terminal", "editing", 
"eyewear", "film noir", "font", "glasses", "graphic design", 
"graphics", "graphics software", "logo", "monochrome", "monochrome photography", 
"multimedia", "multimedia software", "picture editor", "software", 
"song", "sound design", "symbol", "text", "trademark", "tutorial", 
"video editing software", "video editor"), class = "factor"), 
    sum = c(0.53732, 0.484516, 0.648579, 0.457803, 0.475811, 
    0.373938)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

  Start      End Description..Con      sum
1     0 2.333333             text 0.537320
2     0 2.333333             font 0.484516
3     0 2.333333         graphics 0.648579
4     0 2.333333             logo 0.457803
5     0 2.333333   graphic design 0.475811
6     0 2.333333            brand 0.373938
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need changes in your `server` section which I have marked in the code. -

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  source_python("pytho_for_r.py")
  label_retention <- eventReactive(input$update, { # use eventReactive()
    x <- input$link # isolate not needed anymore
    if(x == ""){
      print(x)
      return(NULL)
    }
    else{
      label_retention <- read.csv("label_retention.csv", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
      print(label_retention)
      return(label_retention)
    }
  })

  output$label <- renderTable({
    validate( # use validate() for checks
      need(!is.null(label_retention()), "No Video Available") # use label_retention()
    )
    label_retention() %>%             # use label_retention() to call reactive
      select(Labels = Description..Con, Relative_Audience_Retention = sum) %>%
      mutate_if(is.character, str_to_upper) %>%
      mutate(Relative_Audience_Retention = round(Relative_Audience_Retention, 8)) %>%
      arrange(desc(Relative_Audience_Retention)) 
      # datatable( # need to use DT::renderDT() for this
      # removed datatable(); some args probably need to go in options = list(); see docs
      #   spacing = c("s"), striped = TRUE, bordered = TRUE, colnames = TRUE,
      #   hover = TRUE
      # )
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks a for a swift response, it does help, but I wanted to know that the would `label_retention()` return a dataframe. I am getting an error that says `cannot coerce class ‘c("datatables", "htmlwidget")’ to a data.frame` and it seems none of the dplyr function is working, it just prints the data in the box, but not as a table

Comment: @AnalyticsTeam `label_retention()` contains output of `read.csv()` so should return a dataframe. Can't debug `dplyr` code without knowing what's in `label_retention.csv`. Add output of `dput(head(label_rentention))` to your post.

Comment: @AnalyticsTeam Also, `datatable` is meant to be used with `DT::renderDT`. Either add `DT` library or remove `datatable()` from `renderTable`. Also it is not a good idea to have column named as `sum`. It can create conflicts with function `sum()`.

Comment: Yeah I realised that earlier and have already made that change. I have updated the output you requested

Comment: @AnalyticsTeam see simplified updated answer. Should work if `label_retention.csv` is being read correctly. Also try and rename the `sum` column to something else and update code accordingly.

Comment: @AnalyticsTeam `Descriptions` column is actually named `Description..Con`. I made that change to the code and `dplyr` transformation works for me. The overall `server` code should work now.

Comment: it does work for me as well, and I am able to see the table now, however the `str_to_upper` is somehow not working. Also if you dont mind me asking, is there way I can add scroll to this, as my data overshoots my box

Comment: @AnalyticsTeam Use `stringsAsFactors = F` in `read.csv()` for `mutate_if()` to work. I haven't run your app so don't know about the scroll. I suggest asking a separate question for that with simplified code.

Comment: sure thing, but thanks a lot for all the help and time